# How to add a new key nowadays for which "apt-key add K1" used to be utilized before?

Tags: ubuntu, gnupg, apt

I have the following command

```
wget -q https://download.arangodb.com/arangodb34/DEBIAN/Release.key -O- | sudo apt-key add -
```

Since `apt-key` has become depricated, how should I add a new key?

This warning

```
apt-key is deprecated. Manage keyring files in trusted.gpg.d instead (see apt-key(8)).
```

doesn't imply how to do it precisely.

I've checked out the path

```
ls  /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/

ubuntu-keyring-2012-cdimage.gpg
ubuntu-keyring-2018-archive.gpg
```

but how to do it still? Just create a file? But a key at `https://download.arangodb.com/arangodb34/DEBIAN/Release.key` is in the normal **text** format, and not `gpg`

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to manage the Ubuntu keyring is with [its GNOME GUI](https://itsfoss.com/ubuntu-keyring/), *Password*.

- Press <kbd>System</kbd> and type `pass`.
- Select the *Passwords and Keys* application.

[Gnome documents usage](https://help.gnome.org/users/seahorse/stable/) of that application in detail, including adding a PGP key, should it not be [IOTTMCO](http://onlineslangdictionary.com/meaning-definition-of/iottmco).

Comment: I haven't asked how to manage the Ubuntu keyring via GUI